# Equivalent of Classic maskRE in Modern

Tags: extjs

I am migrating our app from Classic to Modern using sdk 7.4
In classic the Ext.form.field.Text class has a maskRe config that will limit what characters the user can input into the field - for example /[0-9"]/ will limit the input to the digits 0 to 9 and the double quote character.  They can enter as many digits or quote marks as they like - just not any other characters.  Any other character the user may type is ignored.  How can I achieve this in the Modern framework.  inputMask is NOT what I am looking for.  Validators comes close but that just makes the field show as invalid if the user types an invalid character which is annoying for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stripCharsRe`.

Here is the [documentation link](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.field.Text.html#cfg-stripCharsRe).

Comment: Thank you - I also found a bug in Sencha Architect 4.3 whereby stripCharsRe was not being set up properly when using the Modern framework.  Its been reported to Sencha.